# CDN not fully working

Tags: cdn

just finished the CDN set up for our magento store.
Some images/css/js files are loaded fine from cdn server.
But some cdn versions redirect back to our hosting.

I mean some files can be accessed on cdn - example

```
http://cdn.domain.com/media/wysiwyg/logo-dark.png
```

Some redirect, example:

```
http://cdn.domain.com/skin/frontend/rwd/green/images/media/logo.png
```

redirects to

```
http://www.domain.com/skin/frontend/rwd/green/images/media/logo.png
```

What can be the reason for this?

The bytes by domain shows that about 40% sourced by cdn.domain.com and 55% by domain.com. I guess it's not like it supposed to work?

Here are the [settings](http://dropproxy.com/f/C47).

---

Found the problem.
It was caused by htaccess code:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ http://www.domain.com/.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This code supposed to redirect /index.php/ to route.
Why does it mess around with cdn.domain.com?

Comment: Make sure all of your Images/CSS/JS are uploaded to the CDN.  You may also checkout https://github.com/onepica/imagecdn module to help faciliate images.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it's updating your CDN, but I don't have full access to your server setup.

Try this.  It says only rewrite if not on the CDN.  Of course, update domain.com in both cases:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^cdn.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ http://www.domain.com/.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue for Magento 2.

In our case we had forgot to add media resource for a custom sub-folder in the media directory. If this isn't done, access isn't allowed from outside the base domain.

You can add additional folders like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <system>
            <media_storage_configuration>
                <allowed_resources>
                    <custom_folder>folder_name</banner_folder>
                </allowed_resources>
            </media_storage_configuration>
        </system>
    </default>
</config>
```